# Are There Any Standards for RTCs, Similar to JC42 Temp Sensors?

Tags: rtc, standard

When I place a temperature sensor on a board, I like to use a JC42-compliant temperature sensor.  I know of at least half a dozen manufacturers that build these temperature sensors in exactly the same package and utilizing the same set of commands.  The same thing goes for most FLASH memories; one can find series of parts that utilize the same footprints, pinouts, and internal register structure that conform to the JEDEC standard.  Given the current (and I presume, future) environment of component shortages, I'm looking for a similar standard for real-time clocks.  While you can creative with alarms and such, an RTC chip seems like a very standard kind of chip, where there are registers for year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.  I know this because I currently have to support two different chips for a product line at my company.  It would seem that this kind of chip should have a standard along the lines of temperature sensors and FLASH, yet I can't seem to find the applicable standard.  Does any out in the community know if there is such a standard?

Comment: Recommendations for specific products are off-topic for this site.

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation for a specific product.  I am asking if there are any standards, similar to JEDEC-42, for real time clocks.